# How to fix Textmate's autopairing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

I'm editing a .rb file. I've added .rb to Ruby on Rails.

I am very new to Textmate, and I can't find the option that stops the editor from adding {} after every #.

For example, I get this:

```
"pages#{home}"
```

But I want this:

```
"pages#home"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `'pages#home'`
Not `"pages#home"`

`'pages#home'` will be faster because it's not trying to process `#{}` and other embedded ruby.

Only use `""` when you know you're going to embed ruby into the string.

If you really want to disable the `#{}`, turn off the Ruby/Rails bundle.